# Setting up React environment variables for dev and local

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, node-modules, env-cmd

I am new to react and setting up environment variables for my project. Here is what I did..

1. added .env-cmdrc.json as follows

   ```
   {
    "development":{
    "REACT_APP_BASE_URL": "https://servername:port/"
    },
    "staging":{
    "REACT_APP_BASE_URL": "http://servername:port/"
    },
     "local":{
     "REACT_APP_BASE_URL": "http://localhost:port/"
     }
    }
   ```
2. installed npm

> npm install env-cmd or npm install -g env-cmd

3. edited package.json as follows:

   ```
    "start:development": "env-cmd -e development react-scripts start",
    "start:staging": "env-cmd -e staging react-scripts start",
    "start:local": "env-cmd -e local react-scripts start",
    "build:development": "env-cmd -e development react-scripts build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -e staging react-scripts build",
   ```
4. tried - npm run start:development

   was giving me env-cmd error
5. again ran

   npm install env-cmd
6. Now tried - npm run start:development

> Failed to find .rc file at default paths: [./.env-cmdrc,./.env-cmdrc.js,./.env-cmdrc.json] at getRCFile

I am doing it first time and would appreciate any help..what am I missing here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code, but it works well.
Check your code, ensure the location of your config file `.env-cmdrc.json`, it should be placed under root dict of your project (the same level with `package.json`)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using **dotenv** package instead of **env-cmd**.

1. install the package - **npm i dotenv**
2. Create a environment file in your root directory - **.env**
3. Declare a variable - **REACT_APP_URL=http://localhost/....**
4. Use the variable - **process.env.REACT_APP_URL**

In order to start the React application you need to check your package.json file and make sure it contains something like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

If that's in place you can run the following command: **npm start**

---

Now you can start coding :)

Comment: How does that switch to staging and production? It looks like this sets to localhost.

Comment: @J.Gwinner you can manually switch to production by changing the REACT_APP_URL or you can automate that with a bash script.